# after their discharge home

Tags: sentence-structure, modifiers, adverb-placement

The phrase "*after their discharge home*" made me do a double take. Do you think *home* below is an adverb modifying the verb *follow up*?

> This study followed up a cohort of 386 patients aged 65+ for six
>   months *after their discharge home.*

Source:  Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary

Might be stripped down to:

> After their discharge **home**, this study followed up them for six months.

<strike>Even more to:</strike>

> <strike>This study **followed up them home**.</strike>

Comment: I don't think so. It followed up those patients, i.e., it followed them up. It did that for six months after their "discharge home". I'm not sure what would be the best way to explain this syntactically, though.

Comment: Yes you're right @DamkerngT. "After their discharge home, the study ..." the study engaged only after the discharge. Still what I wanted is the parsing of home. Up crawling the Web for two days dumbed me down ;)

Comment: Grammatically an interesting question.  The act of sending a patient home is called the **discharge**.  The verb is being treated as a synonym for **sent** with the same licensing (The patient was *discharged home*) and the noun **discharge** is "retaining" that verbal sense. "After their discharge home".

Comment: Compare: They were resettled west.  After their resettlement west...

Comment: A sentence from Longman's Dictionary could help: *Nurses visit the mother and baby for two weeks **after their discharge from the hospital.*** (from hospital) and (home) are prepositional and adverbial modifiers that modify discharge. The settlement example is very helpful too. Thanks

Comment: The example sentence in Longman's shows how the verb is most often used, especially in formal contexts.  The patient is discharged *from* the hospital, rather than *discharged home*.  The speaker of the phrase in your question is not using the verb in that way, however.

Comment: Yes semantically different but I was all about syntax. So syntactically they are similar as modifiers regardless of being prepositional or adverbial ones.

Comment: I can only offer more examples: *Then they came to New York, to start their climb up the ladder or their walk down the road.* (Isn't it interesting that *their climb the ladder* and *their walk the road* would be ungrammatical?) -- If that example looks ambiguous, syntactically, we could try some other examples, e.g., *In their climb up the empire ladder some even added the name of god to their title, and demanded worship from their citizens on penalty of death*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Very interesting sentences to ponder and to post about. Why don't you do the honors!

Answer (score 1):

What Damkerng T. is pretty much spot on. I must admit I did not know this usage of follow up but according to Merriam-Webster we have:

> Medical Definition of follow up
>
> :  to maintain contact with (a patient) at one or more designated intervals following diagnosis or treatment especially to examine again or monitor the progress of therapy < patients who are followed up after their discharge> < She was discharged on postoperative day 4 and was followed up in the surgery clinic 19 days postoperatively.—Steven L. Bloom et al., The New England Journal of Medicine, 21 Oct. 2010>

Which is really a more extensive explanation of usage 2. of the transitive version of follow up:

> 2
>   :  to maintain contact with (a person) so as to monitor the effects of earlier activities or treatments

In essence then the parsing of your original sentence should be

> The study followed them up after their discharge.

With home being a standard noun explaining where they were discharged to, as opposed to being the place they followed up at. You would need something like

> The study followed up the patients in their home.

If you wanted to get rid of the discharge.

That at least is my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @DRF. Still, how would you parse (parts of speech and relationships between them) home?

Comment: This is what I was looking for: word class or syntactic category

Comment: Ok this was much more complex than I thought. But looking at the way home is used it must be an adverb IMO I will write this up with more explanation later.